# mod_rewrite - Port 80 does not change to 443 when HTTP is explicitly requested

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, mod-rewrite, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, google-openid

I have an app deployed to Elastic Beanstalk whose Tomcat container uses Google OpenID Connect for authentication. I want to redirect all `http` requests to `https`, for which I have the following `mod_rewrite` configuration in a file in `.ebextensions` -

```
files:
    "/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl_rewrite.conf":
        mode: "000644"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
            RewriteRule . https://%{HTTP:Host}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=permanent]
```

Google OAuth2 credentials console has `https://example.com/j_security_check` as an authorized redirect URL. The configuration works fine when either `example.com` or `https://example.com` is requested, whereupon the app is redirected to the mentioned authorized URL.

However, when `http` is explicitly requested - `http://example.com` - the app is being redirected to `https` but `port 80` is still being used. The authorized redirect URL then becomes `https://example.com:80/j_security_check` and I get `Error: redirect_uri_mismatch`.

How can I redirect explicit `http` requests to `https` with the port changed to `443`? The main goal is to match the mentioned authorized redirect URL. If possible, I'd like to implement this with the `.ebextensions` configuration file or a similar solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not with the rewrite rule. The file had to be placed in a specific path within `.ebextensions` for it to work in Tomcat 8. The configuration files had to be setup differently too. Most examples provided were not for Tomcat so I ended up putting them in the wrong location.

**What worked** -

In `/.ebextensions/httpd/conf.d/myconf.conf`, place -

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

and in `/.ebextensions/httpd/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/00_application.conf`, place -

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  <Proxy *:80>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/ retry=0
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
  ProxyPreserveHost on

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
  RewriteRule . https://%{HTTP:Host}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=permanent]

  ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/elasticbeanstalk-error_log
</VirtualHost>
```

*Take note of the use of `.conf` files instead of `.config`. This is important!*

Also, the redirection that I was getting was not genuine. I was not paying close attention, because when I requested `example.com`, the browser cache was serving me `https://example.com`. It was not actually redirecting an `http` request to `https`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you something like this. If it got worked I will give you the explanation.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Comment: That's what I had initially. It didn't work. The rule mentioned in the question is from [AWS' documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redirect-http-https-elb/) for redirecting `http` traffic to `https`.